# How I do override the style of a slds class for lightning components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

New to lwc. I am trying to change the box-shadow color in the vertical navigation.

```
<template>
<div style="width: 220px;">
    <lightning-vertical-navigation>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
            <template for:each={clientsList} for:item="client">
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-item  class="vert-nav-item" key={client.name} label={client.name} name={client.name}></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation>
</div>
```

```
.vert-nav-item{
box-shadow: pink;
```

}

I cannot seem to change the color to pink. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incorrect; [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) takes at minimum two parameters to work (three if you want something other than black).

Here's an example of the fixed CSS:

```
.vert-nav-item {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px pink;
}
```

And here's the [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/KsaWg4jL/1/edit) to test with.

Read the docs at the first link to learn what all the possible parameters are for `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 0):

The box-shadow property attaches one or more shadows to an element

Here is the css syntax of box shadow

```
box-shadow: none|h-offset v-offset blur spread color |inset|initial|inherit;


.vert-nav-item {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px pink;
}
```